# Get index of maximum value along the column axis based on condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape NxM with values between 0 and 1. I want to get the index of maximum value along the column axis only if the value is greater than `0.9` otherwise `-1`.

Eg:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[0.6,0.9,1],[0.3,0.5,0.7]])
```

So the max index output i need for above array `array([2, -1])`.

I have tried using `np.where`

```
arr_filtered = np.where(arr>0.9,arr,-1)
max_index = np.argmax(arr_filtered,axis=1)
```

The output of above code snippet is `array([2, 0])`. which is not matching my expected output. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

1. Find index of max in each row
2. check max of each row > 0.9
3. merge the result above two steps
4. if value is zero replace with -1

```
arr = np.array([[0.6,0.9,1],[0.3,0.5,0.7]])
a = np.argmax(arr, axis=1)
# 1 -> array([2, 2])

b = np.max(arr,axis=1) > 0.9
# 2 -> array([ True, False])

c = a*b
# 3 -> array([2, 0])
c[c==0] = -1
print(c)
# 4 -> array([ 2, -1])
```